# Windows file system filter driver on mapped network drive

Tags: windows, filesystems, filter-driver

Is it possible to attach an FS filter driver on a mapped network drive?
I'm really new to this filter driver work and currently testing a demo version of an SDK. It works fine on my local drive and I was able monitor and even deny file creation. But it doesn't seem to work on a mapped network drive.

So my question is: Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Of course.
You simply need to check in you instance attach if your filesystem type is a network filesystem.
Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nc-fltkernel-pflt_instance_setup_callback), especially the *VolumeDeviceType* and *VolumeFilesystemType* parameters.

Good luck,
Gabriel